# Graph of the approximate value of the square root of numbers by a given formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I basically want to graph this set of approximate values of the square roots of numbers as a result of an algorithm I just saw online. I want to make it into a whole function in order to visualize how close it is to the actual curvature of the function $y = \sqrt {x}$.

Suppose any positive number is can be written in a form

$$a^2 + b$$

where $a^2$ denotes the greatest perfect square less than or equal to the number

then the approximate value of its square root is

$$a + \frac {b} {2a}.$$

Generally,

$$ \sqrt {a^2 + b} ≈ a + \frac {b} {2a}.$$

I don't know how to make this into a graph. I know this topic is too easy for you guys. I just need a small help with this small problem.

Thank you so much.

PS: I already get it. Thank you for all the help I received. I have my own solution below for my own problem now.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yeah, thank you I really need it.

Comment: Your last paragraph is not so welcome. You don't recognize the others' work.

Comment: I've just done the edits. Thank you so much, José Carlos Santos and Yves Daoust. I really appreciate you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take and number $u>0$. Then there is a unique integer $l\geq 0$ such that  $l\leq u<l+1$. This $l$ is denoted by $\lfloor u\rfloor$. Given $x>0$ let $a:=\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$. Thus $a\leq \sqrt{x}<a+1$ and $a^2\leq x<(a+1)^2$. This implies that $a^2$ is the largest perfect square $\leq x$, So you want to graph the function $s$ with $s(x):=f(x)+g(x)$ where $f(x):=\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ and $g(x):=\frac{x-(f(x))^2}{2f(x)}$.
The function $x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$ is called the *floor* function and should be available in your favorable graphing tool.

Edit: [graph with Wolfram alpha from 1 to 10](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20Floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%2B%28x-Floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%5E2%29%2F%282Floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29%20from%201%20to%2010) and [from 1 to 100](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20Floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%2B%28x-Floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%5E2%29%2F%282Floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29%20from%201%20to%20100)

Comment: There is noch integral involved.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link Jens. I can finally see the graph.

Answer (score 1):

The formula

$$\sqrt n\approx a+\frac{b}{2a}=\frac12\left(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor+\frac n{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\right)$$

is exact when $n$ is a perfect square ($n=m^2$), then is linear to the next perfect square, with

$$m^2\to m,\\(m+1)^2-1\to m+1.$$

The largest error occurs right before a perfect square ($n=(m+1)^2-1$). It equals

$$\epsilon=m+1-\sqrt{(m+1)^2-1}
\\=\frac1{m+1+\sqrt{(m+1)^2-1}}
\\\approx\frac1{2\sqrt n}.$$

Hence the *relative error* is on the order of

$$\frac1{2n}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, Yves. I can finally graph it.

Comment: I love your solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand. Thank you so much for all the help.

The greatest perfect square less than or equal the number is equivalent to $\lfloor \sqrt {x}\rfloor$.

And by the actual process of the given algorithm, I saw online, It can be directly put into an expression. It will go like this

$$\sqrt{x} ≈ \lfloor \sqrt {x} \rfloor + \frac { x - \lfloor \sqrt {x} \rfloor ^2} {2\lfloor \sqrt {x} \rfloor} .$$

Which is very helpful in solving for few decimal digits of the square root of any numbers.